# What is a better and faster way to count specific elements in a list than count() in python?

Tags: python, list, optimization, count

I'm trying to solve a hackerrank problem in which I have to print the number of occurrences of a word in a list(in order). My code works fine but the problem is that in a few of the test cases my code didn't manage to execute within the time limits. I've tried a few things to make it a bit faster which I will get into in a moment.
Here is my code:

```
ar = [input() for i in listinput]
tup = tuple(dict.fromkeys(ar))
print(len(tup))
for i in tup:
    print(str(ar.count(i))+" ", end='')
```

I've tried to make the list remove elements that have already appeared like so:

```
ar = [input() for i in listinput]
tup = tuple(dict.fromkeys(ar))
print(len(tup))
for i in tup:
    print(str(ar.count(i))+" ", end='')
    ar.remove(i)
```

Which leads me to conclude that using count() might not have been that efficient for this. I'm still not sure though. Basically what do I need to change to make this code execute faster.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: You don't need to build a `dict` or `tuple` if you are going to use `count`; you can just use `for i in set(ar): ...` directly, though that's still far inferior to using `Counter` as in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Counter() from collections should be faster. [Link to Python library - Collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).
(I am not sure if you had to implement the counter for the hackerrank test or if you could just use a library)

Assuming the input of the following format.

```
ar = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5] # or words
```

We just have to use the Counter function as,

```
import collections
ar = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5]
print(collections.Counter(ar))
```

Output is a Counter object,

```
Counter({9: 5, 5: 4, 1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1})
```

Also, pay attention to the order. You might have to run a loop over the original list and every time you encounter a new word, use the word as a key in the dictionary and set the value of that word from the counter dictionary.
Hope this is faster.